# How can I use toupper in all values of a data frame variable?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has several thousand records.  One record is for a U. S. state abbreviation.  The two character abbreviation can be capitol or small letters.  For example, New York state, might be either ny or NY.  I need all characters to be capitol letters, so the tabulations will include all records from one state with that state.  Otherwise, I get two rows in a state tabulation  one for capitol letter abbreviations and one for small letter abbreviations.

I have tried a number of options, and so far none have worked.  The latest  has a data frame called A1, and within that is the State variable.  That is, the State variable is A1$State.

I wrote a function like this…

```
FixVal <- function(a)
{

    tempstring1 = toupper(a)
    return(tempstring1)

}
```

and then tried several variations on the apply function

```
apply(A1$State, 1, FixVal(A1$State))
apply(A1$State, 2, FixVal(A1$State))
apply(A1, 1, FixVal(A1))
apply(A1, 1, FixVal(A1$State))

apply(A1$State, 1, FixVal(State))
```

The error messages are different for each attempt.  The most recent error message is that “State” is not found in function toupper.

Since I can print “State” using ..
print(A1$State)  I know that it exists and that it is spelled correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `A1$State <- toupper(A1$State)` I think? Don't think you need `apply()` or any fanciness here.

Comment: Thank you!!  Looking back at my notes, I tried that early on, and got an error.  Tried it again, after reading your comment, and it works.  The previous attempt must have had some other error going on. If you put your comment in as an answer, I will mark it "answered". Thank you.